# bootstrap-year-calendar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, calendar

I want to use the bootsrap-year-calendar from this site: http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/

Although it's advertised with easy to use I struggle. I'm using Spring Boot V1.4.1, Bootstrap V3.3.7 and Thymeleaf.

I downloaded all the source code from the software mentioned above and the only thing I'm able to do with the calendar is showing the calendar itself. 
I created a new file called calendar.js where I put all the JavaScript for the custom functions of the calendar. I tried displaying the week-numbers but it doesn't even show them. There are examples on this page with marked dates and those weren't displayed, too.

I tried different orders of the script and css files but unfortunately it didnt't work. I tried other datepickers and those didn't work, too though I followed all instruction given by the installation-page. The only thing working so far is ChartJs

Do I have to change the dependencies in the pom.xml?

I appreciate any help!

Edit:
This is the code of calendar.js :

```
$(function() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

    var redDateTime = new Date(currentYear, 2, 13).getTime();
    var circleDateTime = new Date(currentYear, 1, 20).getTime();
    var borderDateTime = new Date(currentYear, 0, 12).getTime();

    $('#calendar').calendar({ 

        displayWeekNumber: true

        customDayRenderer: function(element, date) {
            if(date.getTime() == redDateTime) {
                $(element).css('font-weight', 'bold');
                $(element).css('font-size', '15px');
                $(element).css('color', 'green');
            }
            else if(date.getTime() == circleDateTime) {
                $(element).css('background-color', 'red');
                $(element).css('color', 'white');
                $(element).css('border-radius', '15px');
            }
            else if(date.getTime() == borderDateTime) {
                $(element).css('border', '2px solid blue');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the code of the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->    
    <link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-year-calendar-master/css/bootstrap-year-calendar.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/css/jquery-3.1.1.min.js}"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

    <!--bootstrap-year-calendar-->
    <script th:src="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-year-calendar-master/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/resources/css/bootstrap-year-calendar-master/js/calendar.js}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div data-provide="calendar"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you do so. When asking a question, be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and be sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but is easy to solve.
On the jS change the hashtag for a dot

> $('#calendar').calendar({

To

> $('.calendar').calendar({

And on the Html, change data-provide for class

> div data-provide="calendar"

To

> div class="calendar"

Comment: Are there multiple calendar controls or just single? By using dot, you are updating everyone

Comment: I´m afraid I'm not sure, I found a bug (was not capable of do a customDayRenderer on any day on an entire august week) so I'am dropping the idea of use this calendar